# Raster domain output polygon has is an empty feature class. Shape_Length and Shape_Area = 0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, polygon-creation, raster-conversion

I am trying to convert a 32-bit floating point raster with 205289 columns and 120615 rows to a polygon using Raster Domain. It creates a feature class that does not contain any polygon.  There is a record in the attribute table but it says zero in the Shape_Length and Shape_Area fields.

Any ideas why I am getting this output? Or other suggestions how to convert this raster to a polygon? I just need a simple polygon to delineate the boundary of my raster.

Comment: Tool works fine for me. Has your input raster got unusual characters in it? Keep it simple, start with a letter, no spaces, hyphens or & symbols.

Comment: @Hornbydd yes, i even tried saving the output to my local drive to shorten the path. i was thinking maybe the raster is too big to convert.

Comment: Hmmm.. Try running it on some other raster just to prove that the tool works for you?

Comment: @Hornbydd i have and it worked for other rasters.

Comment: Is your raster outside your domain if storing in a geodatabase feature class; have you looked at your output extent environment settings; Is the spatial reference of the raster set? That's 3 things that I know of that could cause this issue.

Comment: If you only have a few pixels with data, and the rest are nodata, this tool will give you an empty result. Especially if the data pixels are non-contiguous or only connected diagonally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raster calculator to to assign integer, say 1, to all not null cells. Convert result to polygon, using Raster to polygon